# Am I using list comprehensions wrong?

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension

So my Python code to keep on finding the sum of a number's digits `(9983 = 9+9+8+3 = 29 = 2+9 = 11 = 1+1 = 2)` below isn't working, and it gives me this exception

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['".
```

It was working before when instead of using list comprehension, I did it by iterating through the list normally, so I suspect it's a problem with the list comprehension? Help?

```
x = int(input())
def rec(x):
   if (x<10):
      return x
   return rec(sum(x))
def sum(x):
   lst = [int(y) for y in list(str(x))]
   return sum(lst)
print(rec(x))
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` for your function name, it's a builtin function name and will cause problems.  Note that you have created a recursive function, which you probably didn't intend.  Change the name to avoid the problem.

Comment: As Tom mentioned, that was the problem: `rec` is supposed to be recursive, that's fine, but `sum` is recursive as well and it shouldn't be!

Comment: Never use a name that already exists, from you code or from built-in (in case you'd know that `sum` exists) if not just a warning that'll make avoid a loooot of troubles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in function called [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), and you defined a function with the same name - but you need the original function as part of the solution.

Let's start by renaming your version of `sum` to `summation`, and let's take the opportunity to simplify the code a bit more:

```
def rec(x):
    if x < 10:
        return x
    return rec(summation(x))

def summation(x):
    return sum(int(y) for y in str(x))
```

See how the built-in `sum` was needed inside `summation`? that's why your function must have a different name! And although we could have used a list comprehension, it's easier and more efficient to pass a generator expression to `sum`. Alternatively (but less efficiently) we could have used a list comprehension:

```
def summation(x):
    lst = [int(y) for y in str(x)]
    return sum(lst)
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
rec(9983)
=>2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating confusion for Python ;-)

The problem is in `def sum(x):`, not in the list comprehension. `sum` is a reserved keyword. Just rename the function (and the call to the function) and it works.